# CAS & spring-security-cas with stateless session

Tags: spring-security, jwt, cas, stateless-session

I'm currently working through a spring application which is using stateless session and **JWT** based mechanism for authentication & authorizations.

A new requirement arrived: using CAS v4.0 SSO solution to replace the authentication system. I went through the [CAS documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.0.x/planning/Architecture.html) and the [spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#cas) and saw no sign of "**stateless mode**". Trying to set the spring security session policy to stateless is breaking my CAS integration.

**My intuition would tell me to totally drop the JWT mechanism and switch on classic statefull based sessionid mode to avoid issues. Is there some resource trying to adress a CAS + stateless client? Has someone had experience with it?**